# PHP.INI do not change include_path. WHY?

Tags: php, macos, apache, pear

I found my php.ini, changed its include_path but nothing change.

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/estudos/db_pear.php on line 3

My phpinfo() show that my include_path is just (.:).
My include path in PHP.INI is ('.:/usr/local/share/pear').
My phpinfo() also show PHP.INI in (/etc) and command line (`$php --ini`) show:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

I've already restarted my apachectl and my whole pc, but nothing...
Please I would like to use PEAR framework!
Thanks! Blessings!

Comment: Which `php.ini` are you editing? What is the reported value for _"Loaded Configuration File"_ in the output from `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 1):

I got it, Phill!

`/etc` in phpinfo() is where php.ini will be initialized, so I just put the unique php.ini I had (that was in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4` ) in there and it's work!

I'm happy!

Thanks, my brother for helping - or trying help.